# How the parameters and arguments are interpreted between the functional interface and a function in method reference context

Tags: java

```
interface MyFunc<T> {
  boolean func(T v1, T v2);
}

class Foo {
  private int value;

  Foo(int v) { value = v; }

  boolean isGreater(Foo obj) {   <-- (*)
    return value > obj.value;    <-- (**)    
  }
}

class Demo {
  static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc<T> f, T v) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
      if (f.func(vals[i], v)) 
        count++;

    return count;
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    int count;

    Foo[] values = new Foo[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
      values[i] = new Foo(i);

    count = counter(values, Foo::isGreater, new Foo(5));

    System.out.println("values bigger " + count);
  }
}
```

This code have a function isGreater (*) that count the number of values that are less than a passed value as argument. My confusion is how `interface MyFunc<T>` infer that this return statement (**) that compare two Foo instance variables value have 2 parameters. To make it more clear how `MyFunc<T>` takes `(T v1, T v2)` as parameters and this is a matching with the function `isGreater(Foo obj)` which takes a reference of type Foo as a argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `isGreater` is an *instance* method. How would you call an instance method of `Foo`? You would need an *instance* of `Foo`, in addition to all the parameters required by the method.

In the case of `isGreater`, you actually need two instances of `Foo` to call it (even though it only needs 1 `Foo` as parameter):

```
foo1.isGreater(foo2)
^^^^           ^^^^
```

Also notice how when you use `Foo::isGreater`, you are not giving it any instance of `Foo` to call `isGreater` on! Normally this wouldn't work with an instance method, but the Java language designers saw it coming and allowed this.

In any case, you need an instance of `Foo` on which to call `isGreater` and another instance to pass as the parameter. Therefore, we can "rewrite" `isGreater` as a static method like this:

```
public static boolean isGreater(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
    return foo1.isGreater(foo2);
}
```

The instance on which you call `isGreater` got "promoted" as a parameter! This isn't really want happens under the hood, but this still serves as an explanation of why this is possible in the first place.

Comment: Good answer +1! For my taste there's a bit too much "magic" happening here in the background

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you. I understand it now.